# Stop autolayout from resizing my view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout

Using Storyboards I add a UIView with height of 5px.

At run time the height of that view is increased (could be up to 25px).

When the orientation changes, the height of the view is reverted back to the original 5px.

How can I prevent this? I want the height to remain at whatever it was prior to the orientation change.

Sure I could detect orientation change and then change it back but that looks sloppy because it shrinks then increases right away.

Edit: This may or may not be an autolayout issue. Or might just be the default behavior of storyboards.

Comment: Why don't you uncheck auto layout ?

Comment: Because I use autolayout for other things

Comment: Calm down on the capital letters.

Comment: @pacman321 downvote for capital letters? That has nothing to do with the content of the question. If you think it could be formatted better then contribute and edit the question yourself

Comment: Probably down voted you based on your question and your answer. As that kind of hack will probably bite you in the arse later. Setting the view up correctly is the answer, not hacking layoutSubviews

Comment: @SimonH why might this bite me in the arse later? You are the second person to say this so there may be some validity in it, but I'm trying to learn and understand WHY this is bad practice

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The solution to the problem is to sublcass UIView and override -(void)layoutSubviews

In -(void)layoutSubviews is where I set my desired height

Comment: This is the incorrect approach.  If you're using autolayout you should adjust a view's height by modifying its constraints programmatically.

Comment: @AaronBrager can you provide an example of how I should modify the height constraints programatically

Answer (score 1):

Add a constraint fixing the height, you may also need to remove a constraint. If you show the code or explain how you're setting the constants in the first place can give a more detailed answer.

Other answer is to remove the constraint that stretching the size of your view, may be that you have conflicting constraints.

One more answer could be you need to adjust the priority of an other constraint perhaps one for spacing between views. Again more detail = better answer.

Comment: Not sure if it was an autolayout issue. I answered my own question. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Overriding `-layoutSubviews` is the incorrect approach. If you're using autolayout you should adjust a view's height by modifying its constraints programmatically.

Make a property for your view's height constraint:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *heightConstraint;
```

I put `IBOutlet` there since you said you're making the constraints in a storyboard.  Just drag the height constraint to that property to connect it.  (You could also create the constraint programmatically, in which case you wouldn't use `IBOutlet`.)

Then, whenever you want to change the height:

```
self.heightConstraint.constant = 25;
```